# Where is the 'real' ledger and How is it maintained?

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

In a Hyperledger Fabric network, ledgers which all peers(endorsing peers and committing peers) have are replicated ledgers.

It seems to imply there is a unique 'real/original/genuine' ledger per channel.

I'd like to ask these:

1. Is there a real ledger? If so, where is it(or where is it defined?) and who owns it?
2. Those replicated ledgers are updated by each peer, after VSCC, MVCC validation. Then who updates the 'real' ledger?
3. Does 'World State' only refers to the 'real' ledger?

I'd really appreciate if you answer my questions.

Please tell me if these questions are clarified to you. Thank you!

Comment: This question may better be asked at [cs.se]. "Computer science, also sometimes called computing science, is the science of computation and its applications. This site covers theoretical and applied computer science at any level, including but not limited to …" (*list of subjects*).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand what exactly you mean by **'real'** ledger. There is **one & only** ledger per channel, replicated across all participants per channel. When I say participants, I mean all peers (both endorsing & committing) of an organization's MSP belonging to a given channel.

State DB (a.k.a World state) refers to the database that maintains the current value of a given key. Let me give you an example. You know that a blockchain is a liked list on steroids (with added security, immutability, etc). Say, you have a key **A** with value **100** in **Block 1**. You transact in the following manner.

Block 2 -- A := A-10

Block 15 -- A := A-12

.

.

.

Block 10,000 -- A := A-3

So, after Block 10,000, if you need the current value of key A, you have to calculate the value from Block 1. So to manage this efficiently, Fabric folks implemented a state database that updates the value of a key in the state after every transaction. It's sole responsibility is to improve efficiency. If your state gets corrupted, Fabric will automatically rebuild it from Block 0.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What I mean by 'real' ledger is, as you told that there is one & only ledger per channel, and all peers have replicated ledgers of it. In that sense, what I'd like to ask is where that one & only ledger in the channel and who owns that ledger and who updates it(or how is it updated). Do you happen to know what I'm asking by any chance? Could you please tell me? Thank you!

Comment: As I understand how commitments work, a new block is delivered to all peers with gossip protocol from ordering service, all peers(those who have replicated ledgers) validate it and update the replicated ledgers they have. I can't find how the original ledger is updated and where it is and who owns it in this flow.

Comment: @Linear No one owns the ledger solely. It is jointly owned by the participants of the channel. It is present on all the peers of the organisations participating in the channel.

Comment: That means the ledger which is only one and exists per channel is owned by all peers of the channel, and the peers on the channel just maintain & update replications of that. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: Yes. Correct... Maybe you can mark it as correct and upvote the answer as well.